# Insert data to Chart

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, highcharts

I'm just enter the template of Highchart to make some dashboard. But i don't know to input a value or some data to my chart.

I've tried to give some value with my code with get a count of my data. But when my data null, there is some error. How to make my code allow null ?

````
               name: 'Brands',
               colorByPoint: true,
               data: [{
                   name: 'Jobstreet',
                   y: @Manage_CandidateDTO.GetDataCandidate().Find(m => m.SOURCE == "Jobstreet").SOURCE.Count(),
                   sliced: true,
                   selected: true
               }, {
                   name: 'Internet Explorer',
                       y: @(Manage_CandidateDTO.GetDataCandidate().Find(m => m.SOURCE == "Top Karir").SOURCE.Count());,
               }, {
                   name: 'Firefox',
                       y: 10.85,
               }, {
                   name: 'Other',
                   y: 2.61
               }]
           }] ```

<!--The error is
System.NullReferenceException-->
````

Comment: Does GetDataCandidate return a list? Can you share the code for that model and the current data in your db?

Comment: Hi @momyuke, You have used `highcharts` tag, but the problem doesn't seem to be about a chart - rather about data. If you'll have problems with Highcharts then please provide a demo with hard-coded, exemplary data.